# How to manage bootstrap grid for all screen size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have put four columns in row div as following screen:
[image]
When I minimize screen size that are get align in one column. But I want to align that step by step as screen size decreases:

- Initially they have to in one row i.e. [1X4 grid].
- As screen size minimize first they have to be breakup as 2X2 grid.
- Again if we minimize screen size further then only align in one column[4X1 grid].

My HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!--  colomn # 01 -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Select Prop Type</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Select Report</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Available Fields</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="div_availablefield">
                        Available fields go here..!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End of column # 01 -->

        <!--  colomn # 02 -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="New Report" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label>Account</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Move Right >>>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Move Left <<<" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Move Up" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Move Down" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Save Data" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="Close" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End of column # 02 -->

        <!--  colomn # 03 -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Assigned Fields</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="div_assignedfields">
                        Assigned Fields goes here..!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End of column # 03 -->

        <!--  colomn # 04 -->
        <div class="com-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Report Position</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Custom Caption</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">Custom Mask</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chbox_agent"/> Agent Only?
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chbox_promatch"/> Promatch Only?
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chbox_Caption"/>Blank Caption?
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End of column # 04 -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/999tqgfd/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply these column classes

```
col-xs 12 col-sm-9 col-md-4     
col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2     
col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4     
col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.